# unable to install joomla 3.1 with php 6

Tags: php, joomla, installation, runtime-error

I tried everything but unable to solve this error and issue with joomla not sure why they have made things so complicated without explaining much. I am using Appserv with PHP 6.0.0 and joomla's new version 3.1. I have extracted the whole zip in my www root directory but every time when i check web url it takes  me

http: // localhost/installation/index.php

and error shows as

Fatal error: Interface 'JsonSerializable' not found in

C:\AppServ\www\eshaheen\libraries\joomla\registry\registry.php on line 22

I searched on google but did not find any answer then i opened the registry.php file and added explicitely another import as

import('compat.JsonSerializable') doing that the above error is gone but everything is blank...

Kindly guide me how to install joomla...

regards

Comment: PHP6 isn't out yet do you mean PHP5? Make sure you have downloaded Joomla properly, looks to me like `JsonSerializable` isn't being included

Comment: php6? Where did you get it?

Comment: it shows on my phpinfo PHP Version 6.0.0-dev and i have downloaded new version of appserv which is 2.6.0 link is this one http://www.appservnetwork.com/

Comment: JsonSerializable  is included already inside the compat folder as i have written when i use explicitly inclusion of compat.JsonSerializable then it shows a blank page without error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using outdated software. PHP6 development was closed and was never released. Actual version of PHP is 5.4.

Use other web server solution stack package of [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29). For example: [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP)

Comment: i am back with 5.3.2 php now things are working back as normal...i didnt realize it never release